# select only HH:MM:SS (hour, minutes and seconds) from timestamp column in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date

I have a postgresql database with a column with timestamptz data (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and I want to do a query only of the HH:MM:SS.

In the example, "ingested" column name is the one with the timesamptz

`select ingested from my_database`

This is an data example: 2020-12-23 12:18:13
How can I get 12:18:13 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to time:

```
select ingested::time
```

To avoid the milliseconds:

```
select ingested::time(0)
```

Comment: Yes! it worked 
select ingested::time from classifier_db
Thanks!